# No Access to NodeJS Express App hosted on Google Compute Engine

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a f1-micro instance on google cloud. IN installed ubuntu 14.04, NodejS 0.10 and mongoDB. Now I have made an express application with yeoman which works perfectly on localhost. But when I try to run it in the instance, I can not access it!

Here' what I do:

1. Commit local code to BitBucket
2. Clone code from BitBUcket to Google Compute Engine through SSH
3. run command **grunt**
4. Access the external IP provided by Google with port no. on browser but it says *This webpage is not available*

Here is my source code:

** app.js **

```
'use strict';

// Module dependencies.
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    errorhandler = require('errorhandler');

var app = module.exports = exports.app = express();

app.locals.siteName = "Server";

// Connect to database
var db = require('./config/db');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


// Bootstrap models
var modelsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'models');
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file) {
  require(modelsPath + '/' + file);
});

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if ('development' == env) {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(errorhandler({
        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
    }));
    app.set('view options', {
        pretty: true
    });
}

if ('test' == env) {
    app.use(morgan('test'));
    app.set('view options', {
        pretty: true
    });
    app.use(errorhandler({
        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
    }));
}

if ('production' == env) {
    app.use(morgan());
     app.use(errorhandler({
        dumpExceptions: false,
        showStack: false
    }));
}

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Bootstrap routes
var routesPath = path.join(__dirname, 'routes');
fs.readdirSync(routesPath).forEach(function(file) {
  app.use('/', require(routesPath + '/' + file));
});

// Bootstrap api
var apiPath = path.join(__dirname, 'api');
fs.readdirSync(apiPath).forEach(function(file) {
  app.use('/api', require(apiPath + '/' + file));
});

// Start server
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', port, app.get('env'));
});
```

** Gruntfile.js **

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  grunt.initConfig({
    // Configure a mochaTest task
    mochaTest: {
      test: {
        options: {
          reporter: 'spec'
        },
        src: ['test/**/*.js']
      }
    },
    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: true,
      },
      express: {
        files:  [ '*.js','routes/*.js', 'models/*.js', 'config/*.js','api/*.js'  ],
        tasks:  [ 'express:dev' ],
        options: {
          spawn: false // Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
        }
      }
    },
    express: {
      options: {
        port : 3000,
        node_env: 'development'
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: 'app.js',
          node_env: 'development'
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          script: 'app.js',
          node_env: 'production'
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000' 
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', 'mochaTest');

  grunt.registerTask('server', function(arg) {
    if(arg && arg == 'prod')
    {
      grunt.task.run([
        'express:prod',
        'open',
        'watch'
      ]);
    }
    else
    {
      grunt.task.run([
        'express:dev',
        'open',
        'watch'
      ]);
    }
  });
  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'server' ]);
  grunt.registerTask('dist', [ 'server:prod' ]);

};
```

I tried changing the app.listen with Google provided Internal IP but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: OK so far, I changed the port to 80 and looks like it works. However I would want to use port 3000 and don't know any way of aloowing it in the google cloud console

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay so I just figured it out. It was actually very simple. 
The problem was with the port only. I just needed to change the firewall setting to allow the ports from any source. that's it.

1. Go to Google Cloud console.
2. Networking > Firewall Rules.
3. Find the entry "default-allow-internal" with tcp and udp ranges 1-65535 . Edit it and change the source filter to allow it from any source.

   4. Restart the app with. It should work now.

UPDATE 27 April 2017 : The flow is changed little bit now on GCE. Edit the source filter -> ip range to 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: For me, HTTP/HTTPS traffic wasn't going to my application port (wasn't the default) so I had to edit the default-allow-http, default-allow-https firewall rule.